# bash-like last command in history using up-down arrow keys in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, command-history

In bash, we can use the up and down arrow keys to get the last or n<sup>th</sup> previous command in history.

Can we do this in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man zshzle` you should be able to

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> next history
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> previous history

`man zshzle`:

```
down-history (unbound) (^N) (unbound)
       Move to the next event in the history list

up-history (unbound) (^P) (unbound)
       Move to the previous event in the history list.
```

### Oh-my-zsh

Also, not sure if you know already, but there is also [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). This customization of zsh does come with <kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>up</kbd> as well as previously mentioned <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for next/previous in history list, respectively